# Strikethrough with Color lines along rows and columns in matrices

Tags: pdftex, color, line

It works like to get
[image]

Can someone see how to fix this to work for both rows and columns?

Here I have tried :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
  d_{11}\makebox(-10,0){\rule[-13.5ex]{01.4pt}{3\normalbaselineskip}} 
     & d_{12} & d_{13} \makebox(-15,0){\rule[1.5ex]{3\normalbaselineskip}{0.4pt}} \\
  d_{21}  & d_{22} & d_{23}  \\
 d_{31} & d_{32}  & d_{33}  
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `nicematrix` package in combination with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
\[\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\begin{bNiceMatrix}
    d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} \\
    d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} \\
    d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33}  
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle, draw=red, inner sep=6pt] (circle) at (1-2) {};
        \draw[red] (circle) -- (1-1.west);
        \draw[red] (circle) -- (1-3.east);
        \draw[red] (circle) -- (3-2.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]